# Is Groupwise not supported in Evolution?

Tags: 11.10, evolution

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10, existing Groupwise accounts do not work in Evolution.
If I try to create a new account, there is no option to choose a Groupwise account.
It appears that this functionality is no longer built in to Ubuntu 11.10 and the package "evolution-groupwise" is not available in the repositories...

Answer (score 3):

Transcribed answer from the Ubuntu forums:

Start by installing git

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Next, download the source code (several commands)

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/evolution-groupwise
cd evolution-groupwise
git checkout -b 3.2.0-patch EVOLUTION_GROUPWISE_3_2_0

# This is the patch for the SOAP port bug
git cherry-pick 3aae80f55d5fd565274f19210564e74d5350a66c
```

Using any editor, edit `configure.ac` at about line 48 add the line

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(gthread-2.0, g_thread_init)
```

Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution
```

Compile

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Last, using any editor, edit `/etc/services` add in the lines

```
groupwise 1677/tcp
groupwise 1677/udp
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a temporary solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859907

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.